# Can names of private functions inside classes be repeated?

Tags: class, function, php

```
class One
{
  private function thisfn()
  {}
}
class Two
{
  private function thisfn()
  {}
}
```

is this legit? By the way, does it matter whether it's a private or public function inside a class?

And also, can I create a new function named `thisfn()` **outside** of any class (and make it public)? like:

```
 function thisfn()
{}
```

Comment: You do realize it's faster to run that code than it was to ask this question?

Comment: You're definitely right. I was just trying to figure out if this is a correct method to do things. Often PHP doesn't pop error notifications even though improper code was written.
Do excuse me for wanting to ask experienced programmers on their opinion. I don't think any of my questions are foolish or inappropriate, but if you do, please tell me so, so that I can improve them to fit your opinion.

Btw if stackoverflow has a manual for "which question is appropriate and which isn't" I would appreciate it if you could direct me to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is legit as long as you don't redeclare the same method name within the same class.

Declaring a function outside the scope of the classes with the same name is also valid.